# Detecting onChange event of Select2 in EasyAdmin

Tags: jquery-select2, easyadmin

I am using [EasyAdmin](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html) Bundle, which seems to use [Select2](https://select2.org/) for internal select form fields. I am trying to capture the *onChange* event, but I cannot figure out why the following code does not work:

```
$('#mySelect2Id').on('change', function () {
    console.log($(this).value());
})
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see anything within the console when I change the value of a Select2. Has someone experienced similar issues? Thanks for your help.

Comment: is the DOM loaded by the time you are assigning the event? What happens when you log the length of the selector before assigning the event `console.log($('#mySelect2Id').length);`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed myself.
It looks like the problem appears if you import jquery in webpack, together with EasyAdminBundle.